# Customize EXISTING Wordpress "Posts" template

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress, I'm trying to convert a static html/css template to wordpress theme. It is going fine so far, everything is in place EXCEPT the "posts" section.
You can load your own custom template to PAGES but I don't know how to do the same to the POSTS!
I don't want to make a hole new 'Custom Post Type' because it looks like a difficult and unnecessary process. Can't I just tweak the existing 'posts' html/php code? I can't find the .php file in the base folder, I'm confused, how does this thing work?

Comment: I think you need to edit single.php file for default post format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress is based on a template hierarchy, so for posts you have three files that can be called: single.php, singular.php or index.php, in this order. If you have a single.php file that one is used for posts, if not it fall-backs to singular.php and eventually to index.php.

You can check the hierarchy here: https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png